# json/rest api: how to get the count of nodes matching the specific value

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have data in db.json (4000+ records). I am using angular httpclient to display the data (using CRUD operations).

One of the columns is Gender. Now, I wanted to know the count of males, females, and others.

What do I need to write in my typescript to know the count and display number of males, females, and others out of all records?

app.component.html

```
{{impactCount.applicable}}  
{{impactCount.fyi}}
```

app.component.ts

```
impactCount = {
    applicable: 0,
    fyi: 0
  }

     getLatestUser() {
    this.commonService.getAllUser().subscribe((response) => {
      this.allUser = response;
      this.totalRecords = this.allUser.length;
      this.allUser.forEach(row => this.impactCount[row.impact]++);
    })
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple loop and add two more variables called `maleCount` and `femaleCount`

```
genderCount = {
    male: 0;
    female: 0;
    other: 0;
}

getLatestUser() { 
    this.service.getAllUser().subscribe((response) => { 
        this.allUser = response; 
        this.totalRecords = this.allUser.length;

        this.allUser.forEach(row => {
            if (row.gender === 'Male') {
                this.genderCount.male++;
            } else if (row.gender === 'Female') {
                this.genderCount.female++;
            } else {
                this.genderCount.other++;
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Alternatively, if the gender option in the db is going to be 'male', 'female', and 'other', you can access them like this and cut down on code.

```
this.allUser.forEach(row => this.genderCount[row.gender]++);
```

Comment: getLatestUser() {
this.service.getAllUser().subscribe((response) => { this.allUser = response; this.totalRecords = this.allUser.length; }) }

Comment: this is the getlatestuser function written n ngOnInit() { this.getLatestUser(); }

Comment: now, i have need to show the count of gender (male, female n other) as heading like Male: 976, Female: 2879, Other: 242

Comment: @KunalVijan I updated my answer and changed the 3 variables into an object. I don't know what your user object looks like, so you might have to edit a couple of things to get the data you need

Comment: i have updated the code but i am still getting 0

Comment: entire code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214192/i-wanted-to-update-multiple-records-at-a-time-to-json-from-angular

Comment: did you change the `=== 'male'` to `=== 'Male'` and same with female and other? Because when you change the if statements to match what is in your database, it works [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bsrwmh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: although there is a small issue when I am updating any record it's showing wrong count n i need to reload the page again to get the correct count

Comment: @KunalVijan set the counts to 0 and then call the code I added again after you update

Comment: impactCount = {
    applicable: 0, notapplicable: 0, fyi: 0 
  }  

n shall i call the entire  foreach function again in update user. sorry for that. can you update stackblitz. it would take a min for you n ages for me

Comment: I updated the stackblitz with what I think you're asking for.

Comment: can i ask for something else as well if you have sometime.. that would be really really helpful... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214192/how-do-i-add-functionality-to-update-multiple-records-at-a-time-to-json-from-ang

Comment: I'm sorry but this might be something you have to ask someone you know to walk through it with you. That is going to be a major change to how data is being passed around, and playing in the stackblitz there are a couple of bugs (like the cancel not reverting the value) that need to be solved first before moving to a batch update.

Comment: i need your assistance in showing count for nested nodes impact instead of parent. what changes i should do it in function?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217548/angular-ts-json-from-total-records-how-to-know-the-count-of-matching-the-specif