# How do I add functionality to update multiple records at a time to json from angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, httpclient

I am using angular httpclient to do the crud operations. I have an edit option for every record but I wanted to update multiple records at a time by selecting the checkbox and click on the update button.

Can you please look into it and help me to achieve the same to have a checkbox before impact for every row and select click on the edit button, select updated option n click on update button to update all those selected records.

Also, If I can get the count of how many applicable, not applicable, and FYI out of those records that would be really helpful.

common.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  createUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/users", user);
  }
  getAllUser() {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/users");
  }
  updateUser(user: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put("http://localhost:3000/users/" + user.id, user);
  }
  deleteUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.delete("http://localhost:3000/users/" + user.id);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from './common.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'db-poc1';
  allUser: any;
  isEdit = false;
  isView = false;
  isBatchEdit = false;
  totalRecords: any;
  page: Number = 1;
  currentImpact: string = '';

  isNonTrade: boolean = false
  checkAllNonTrades: boolean = false

  changeTradesByCategory(event) {
    if (event.target.name == 'nontrades') {
      this.isNonTrade = true
    }

    if (this.isNonTrade && this.checkAllNonTrades) {
      event.target.checked = true
    }
  }

  userObj = {
    id: '', first_name: '', last_name: '', email: '', gender: '', ip_address: '', impact: ''
  }

  impactCount = {
    applicable: 0, notapplicable: 0, fyi: 0 
  }

  batchUpdateUsers = [];

  constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLatestUser();
  }
  
  checkboxClicked() {
    this.batchUpdateUsers = this.allUser.filter(row => row.checked);
    this.isView  = false;
    this.isBatchEdit = this.batchUpdateUsers.length > 0;
    this.currentImpact = this.userObj.impact;
  }

  selectAllClicked(event) {
    this.isBatchEdit = true;
    const checked = event.target.checked;
    this.allUser.forEach(item => item.selected = checked);
    this.batchUpdateUsers = checked;
    this.isBatchEdit = checked > 0;
    this.currentImpact = this.userObj.impact;
  }

  addUser(formObj: any) {
    this.commonService.createUser(formObj).subscribe((response) => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    })
  }

  getLatestUser() {
    this.commonService.getAllUser().subscribe((response) => {
      this.allUser = response;
      this.totalRecords = this.allUser.length;
      this.getApplicableCounts();
      this.allUser.forEach(row => row.checked = false);
    })
  }

  getApplicableCounts() {
    this.impactCount = {applicable: 0,notapplicable: 0,fyi: 0}
    this.allUser.forEach(row => {
      if (row.impact === 'Applicable') {
        this.impactCount.applicable++;
      } else if (row.impact === 'Not Applicable') {
         this.impactCount.notapplicable++;
      } else if (row.impact === 'FYI') {
        this.impactCount.fyi++;
      }
    });
  }

  editUser(user: any) {
    this.isEdit = true;
    this.userObj = user;
    this.allUser.forEach(user => user.checked = false);
    this.currentImpact = user.impact;
  }

  deleteUser(user: any) {
    this.commonService.deleteUser(user).subscribe(() => {      
      this.getLatestUser();
    })
  }

  updateUser() {
    this.isEdit = !this.isEdit;
    this.userObj.impact = this.currentImpact;
    this.commonService.updateUser(this.userObj).subscribe(() => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    })
    this.getApplicableCounts();
  }

  cancelEdit() {
    this.isEdit = false;
    this.isView = false;    
  }

  viewUser(user: any) {
    this.isView = true;
    this.userObj = user;
  }

  cancelBatchEdit() {
    this.isBatchEdit = false;
    this.allUser.forEach(user => {user.checked = false});
  }

  batchUpdateUser() {
    this.isBatchEdit = false;
    const batchUpdateUserList = [];
    this.allUser.forEach(user => {
      if (user.checked) {
        user.impact = this.currentImpact
        batchUpdateUserList.push(user);
        user.checked = false;
        this.commonService.updateUser(user).subscribe(() => {
          this.getLatestUser();
        })
      }
    });

    this.commonService.updateUser(this.userObj).subscribe(() => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    })

    this.getApplicableCounts();
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="text-right toal-records">Total: {{totalRecords}}</div>

  <div class="skills">
    <ul class="labels">
      <li>Applicable</li>
      <li>Not Applicable</li>
      <li>FYI</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="lines">
      <li class="line l--0"><span class="line__label">0</span></li>
      <li class="line l--1"><span class="line__label">1</span></li>
      <li class="line l--2"><span class="line__label">2</span></li>
      <li class="line l--3"><span class="line__label">3</span></li>
      <li class="line l--4"><span class="line__label">4</span></li>
      <li class="line l--5"><span class="line__label">5</span></li>
      <li class="line l--6"><span class="line__label">6</span></li>
      <li class="line l--7"><span class="line__label">7</span></li>
      <li class="line l--8"><span class="line__label">8</span></li>
      <li class="line l--9"><span class="line__label">9</span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="charts">
      <div class="chart chart--dev">
        <ul class="chart--horiz">
          <li class="chart__bar" [style.width]="impactCount.applicable * 10 + '%'"></li>
          <li class="chart__bar" [style.width]="impactCount.notapplicable * 10 + '%'"></li>
          <li class="chart__bar" [style.width]="impactCount.fyi * 10 + '%'"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <table class="table table-sm table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" name="allNonTrades" (change)="selectAllClicked($event)">        
        </th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>ID Address</th>
        <th>Impact</th>
        <!-- <th></th> -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="record-row" (click)="viewUser(user)" *ngFor="let user of allUser | paginate: { id: 'listing_pagination', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page, totalItems: totalRecords }">
        <td><input *ngIf="!isEdit"  name="nontrades" [checked]="user.selected" (change)="changeTradesByCategory($event)" [(ngModel)]="user.checked" type="checkbox" (change)="checkboxClicked()"></td>
        <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
        <td>{{user.ip_address}}</td>
        <td>{{user.impact}}</td>
        <!-- <td>
          <button *ngIf="!isEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="editUser(user)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModel">Edit</button>
        </td> -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <pagination-controls id="listing_pagination" directionLinks="true" (pageChange)="page = $event"></pagination-controls>
  
  <div *ngIf="isView" class="view-details">
    <ul>
      <li>First Name <br />{{userObj.first_name}}</li>
      <li>Last Name <br />{{userObj.last_name}}</li>
      <li>Email <br />{{userObj.email}}</li>
      <li>Gender <br />{{userObj.gender}}</li>
      <li>IP Address <br />{{userObj.ip_address}}</li>
      <li>Impact <br />{{userObj.impact}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <form #myForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="impact" [disabled]="!isBatchEdit" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="currentImpact">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Change Impact</option>          
        <option>Applicable</option>
        <option>Not Applicable</option>
        <option>FYI</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" [disabled]="!isBatchEdit" (click)="batchUpdateUser(); myForm.reset()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-update mr-2">
      Update
      </button>
    <button type="button" [disabled]="!isBatchEdit" (click)="cancelBatchEdit(); myForm.reset()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Cancel</button>
  </form>

  <!-- <div *ngIf="isEdit">
    <form #myForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="impact" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="currentImpact">
          <option>Applicable</option>
          <option>Not Applicable</option>
          <option>FYI</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="updateUser()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-update mr-2" *ngIf="isEdit">Update</button>
      <button type="button" (click)="cancelEdit()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Cancel</button>
    </form>
  </div> -->
</div>
```

db.json

```
{
"users": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Kunal",
  "last_name": "Vijan",
  "email": "vijan87@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "1.1.1.1",
  "impact": "Applicable"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Kunal",
  "last_name": "Vijan",
  "email": "vijan87@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "1.1.1.1",
  "impact": "Not Applicable"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "first_name": "Kunal",
  "last_name": "Vijan",
  "email": "vijan87@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "1.1.1.1",
  "impact": "FYI"
}
]
}
```

Comment: I got curious on how to add this functionality so I played with it in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bsrwmh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). This should at least help you get started. I had to add a a new variable to your user model called `checked` for the checkbox. you will probably have to remove that before sending it to the server.

Comment: it's actually updating only the last record. what i need to write in the service for batchupdate function?

Comment: @rhavelka updated code

Comment: if you can please help me with this last thing it would be really great

Comment: or in the component batchUpdateUser() {
    this.isBatchEdit = false;
    const batchUpdateUserList = [];
    this.allUser.forEach(user => {
      if (user.checked) {
        user.impact = this.currentImpact
        batchUpdateUserList.push(user);
        user.checked = false;
      }
    });

    this.commonService.updateUser(this.userObj).subscribe(() => {
      this.getLatestUser();
    })

    this.getApplicableCounts();    
  }

Comment: db.json i m using json-server accessing using httpclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your batch update function. You populate the `batchUpdateUserList` but then you send the `this.userObj` to the server. The `this.userObj` is a single record and is not going to give you the batch update you want.

```
  batchUpdateUser() {
    this.isBatchEdit = false;
    const batchUpdateUserList = []; // objects to 
    this.allUser.forEach(user => {
      if (user.checked) {
        user.impact = this.currentImpact
        batchUpdateUserList.push(user);
        user.checked = false;
      }
    });

    this.commonService.updateUser(this.userObj).subscribe(() => {
      this.getLatestUser();      
    }); 
  }
```

I had a comment in the function that was saying you need to create a new `this.commonService.batchUpdate()` call for the server, but if is not possible to create a new call that sends a list of users for update, then you can do the following

```
  batchUpdateUser() {
    this.isBatchEdit = false;
    const batchUpdateUserList = []; // objects to 
    this.allUser.forEach(user => {
      if (user.checked) {
        user.impact = this.currentImpact
        batchUpdateUserList.push(user);
        user.checked = false;

        this.commonService.updateUser(user).subscribe();
      }
    });

    this.getLatestUser();   
  }
```

but it is not recommended because this is going to be slow and buggy for large updates. You can use a `forkJoin` to solve this issue, but it would prefered if you would create a new service that sends a list to the server for update. You can look at the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bsrwmh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for the example but I didn't update it with this code because the project isn't connected to a server.

Comment: One last thing, I have added the select all option on the table header and need to select all and update all records at once. It is selecting all the records on checkbox select but not updating. Can you please look into it?

Comment: getting error "core.js:4442 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:3000/users/", ok: false, …}"