# angular/ts/json: from total records how to know the count of matching the specific values

Tags: json, angular, filter, count, rest

From the below data how to get the count of applicable impact, not applicable impact n FYI impact for assigned_to nested record instead of parent.

So, the expected results will be:

```
For 1st Record
    Applicable:2 Not Applicable: 1
For 2nd Record
    Applicable:1 Not Applicable: 1
```

db.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Male",
    "last_name": "Record",
    "email": "male.record@gmail.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "dob": "01-01-1987",
    "impact": "Not Applicable",
    "score": "Updated",
    "checked": false,
    "assigned_to": [
      {
        "co_score": 54,
        "dl": "CAT1",
        "sub_impact": "Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      },
      {
        "co_score": 20,
        "dl": "CAT2",
        "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      },
      {
        "co_score": 99,
        "dl": "CAT1",
        "sub_impact": "Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Female",
    "last_name": "Record",
    "email": "female.record@gmail.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "dob": "31-12-1987",
    "impact": "Not Applicable",
    "checked": false,
    "score": "Updated",
    "assigned_to": [
      {
        "co_score": 54,
        "dl": "CAT1",
        "sub_impact": "Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      },
      {
        "co_score": 20,
        "dl": "CAT2",
        "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Male",
    "last_name": "Record Another",
    "email": "male.recordanother@gmail.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "dob": "31-10-2017",
    "impact": "Not Applicable",
    "checked": false,
    "score": 25,
    "assigned_to": [
      {
        "co_score": 100,
        "dl": "CAT3",
        "sub_impact": "Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      },
      {
        "co_score": 2,
        "dl": "CAT2",
        "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Male",
    "last_name": "One More Record",
    "email": "male.onemorerecord@gmail.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "dob": "08-08-1984",
    "impact": "Applicable",
    "id": 6,
    "checked": false,
    "score": 67,
    "assigned_to": [
      {
        "co_score": 4,
        "dl": "CAT1",
        "sub_impact": "Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      },
      {
        "co_score": 85,
        "dl": "CAT3",
        "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Female",
    "last_name": "Another Record",
    "email": "female.anotherrecord@gmail.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "dob": "2000-07-15",
    "impact": "Applicable",
    "id": 7,
    "checked": false,
    "score": 85,
    "assigned_to": [
      {
        "co_score": 34,
        "dl": "CAT3",
        "sub_impact": "Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      },
      {
        "co_score": 55,
        "dl": "CAT2",
        "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "first_name": "New",
    "last_name": "Record",
    "email": "new.record@gmail.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "dob": "2020-12-17",
    "impact": "Not Applicable",
    "score": 60,
    "assigned_to": [
      {
        "co_score": 94,
        "dl": "CAT1",
        "sub_impact": "Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      },
      {
        "co_score": 85,
        "dl": "CAT3",
        "sub_impact": "Not Applicable",
        "comments": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

app.component.ts

```
getApplicableCounts() {
this.impactCount = {applicable:0, notapplicable:0, fyi: 0}
this.allUser.forEach(row => {
  row.assigned_to.forEach(sub => {
    console.log(sub.sub_impact)
    if (sub.sub_impact === 'Applicable') {
      this.impactCount.applicable++;
    } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'Not Applicable') {
       this.impactCount.notapplicable++;
    } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'FYI') {
      this.impactCount.fyi++;
    }
  });
});
getLatestUser() {
    this.commonService.getAllUser().subscribe((response) => {
      this.allUser = response;
      this.totalRecords = this.allUser.length;
      console.log(this.totalRecords);
    })
  }
ngOnInit() {
    this.getLatestUser();
  }
```

What should I write in my getLatestUser function to display the count of applicable: , not applicable: , n fyi:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65186338/8947748) when I was solving a different problem. To get the counts of the impact you need to add the following variable and function:

```
impactCount = {
   applicable: 0,
   notApplicable: 0,
   fyi: 0
};

getImpactCounts() {
  this.impactCount = {applicable: 0, notApplicable: 0, fyi: 0};

  this.allUser.forEach(row => {
    if (row.impact === 'Applicable') {
      this.impactCount.applicable++;
    } else if (row.impact === 'Not Applicable') {
      this.impactCount.notApplicable++;
    } else if (row.impact === 'FYI') {
      this.impactCount.fyi++;
    }
  });
}
```

and then add it to the html as such

```
<div>
  Applicable: {{impactCount.applicable}}
  Not Applicable: {{impactCount.notApplicable}}
  FYI: {{impactCount.fyi}}
</div>
```

and then all you need to do is call `getApplicableCounts()` from your `getLatestUser()` function and any time data changes (so pretty much ever crud call). Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bsrwmh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that is also linked in the comment section of the other question.

Comment: i need your assistance in showing count for nested nodes impact instead of parent. what changes i should do it in function?

Comment: i tried getApplicableCounts() {
    this.impactCount = {applicable:0, notapplicable:0, fyi: 0}
    this.allUser.forEach(row => {
      if (row.sub_impact === 'Applicable') {
        this.impactCount.applicable++;
      } else if (row.sub_impact === 'Not Applicable') {
         this.impactCount.notapplicable++;
      } else if (row.sub_impact === 'FYI') {
        this.impactCount.fyi++;
      }
    });
  } it's not showing up the count

Comment: tried row.assigned_to.sub_impact is also not bringing up the result

Comment: assigned_to is an array. you need to loop over them `row.assigned_to.forEach(sub => {console.log(sub.sub_impact)})`

Comment: this loop will be under this.allUser.forEach loop? this.allUser.forEach(row => {
      row.assigned_to.forEach(sub => {
        console.log(sub.sub_impact)
        if (sub.sub_impact === 'Applicable') {
          this.impactCount.applicable++;
        } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'Not Applicable') {
           this.impactCount.notapplicable++;
        } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'FYI') {
          this.impactCount.fyi++;
        }
      });       });

Comment: @KunalVijan yes, it needs to be under the `allUser.forEach` because that's where the `row` variable lives. your code looks good to me if you want to get overall totals and not totals for each individual row.

Comment: If I am putting this under alluser.forEach loop it's showing me the total for all instead of specific of that record. I have added the screenshot of the console for your reference.

Comment: added the entire json for reference. it's showing up the total for all as in 7 not applicable and 6 applicable

Comment: tried this : this.allUser.row.assigned_to.forEach(sub => {        
      if (sub.sub_impact === 'Applicable') {
        this.impactCount.applicable++;
      } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'Not Applicable') {
         this.impactCount.notapplicable++;
      } else if (sub.sub_impact === 'FYI') {
        this.impactCount.fyi++;
      }
    }); didn't bring any result

Comment: I am going to be mean here, but there is a simple solution, I know you can figure it out, I am not your employee, I'm not going to build your app for you. You have a background in programming, you have been part of the community for 3 years. You just need to figure out what variable you need to populate to get a count for each row instead of an overall count.

Comment: I tried some of the options but it didn't work me that's why I was looking for help. I will try to figure it out myself and thanks a ton for your help in the past.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226114/discussion-between-kunal-vijan-and-rhavelka).

Comment: can you help me with this? sorry, but i am not able to figure it out